# android - I am not able to play video from self signed https url

Tags: android, video, https, android-videoview

I tried to play video from my server which has self signed https server but it does not work. It works only if the url is http. I tried to override the setVideoURI method of the VideoView class without success.

The error is 
MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException! 
MediaPlayer: Error (261,-1003)

I tested on real device with Android 4.2
I can play the video in VLC using same https url of course.

Any advice?

```
package com.mp.samplecode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {

    public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setVideoURI(uri);
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }
            }};

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can play the video in VLC using same https url of course" -- then VLC has a bug, as it should be failing to connect due to not being able to validate the SSL certificate. With respect to `VideoView`, not only will your `TrustManager` cause your app to be banned from the Play Store (if relevant), but `VideoView` does not use `HttpsURLConnection`. Prior to Android 7.0, I do not know of a way to play back media from a Web server secured via a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Copy this following method and paste it in your class. Call it before any service hit

> Kotlin Developers should use this to accept self signed certificate:

```
private fun disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
        val hostnameVerifier = object: HostnameVerifier {
            override fun verify(s:String, sslSession: SSLSession):Boolean {
                return true
            }
        }
        val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object: X509TrustManager {
            override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            //val acceptedIssuers:Array<X509Certificate> = null
            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
            override fun checkClientTrusted(arg0:Array<X509Certificate>, arg1:String) {// Not implemented
            }
            @Throws(CertificateException::class)
            override fun checkServerTrusted(arg0:Array<X509Certificate>, arg1:String) {// Not implemented
            }
        })
        try
        {
            val sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, java.security.SecureRandom())
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier)
        }
        catch (e: KeyManagementException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

> JAVA use this code :

```
private void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {// Not implemented
                }
                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {// Not implemented
                }
            } };

            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```